# How can I make my room sound proof?

Tags: sound

I make educational videos in my room and I feel uncomfortable when someone(my parents especially) put ears and try to hear what I am saying. Is there an easy and not costly way by which the sound does not reach outside the room even after closing the doors.

Comment: Thank you for the question. This type of room treatment  is a better fit  for our **[Home Improvement site](http://diy.stackexchange.com)** than something needing a life hack. If you run into a hurdle which is going to need a bit of out-of-the-box thinking, Lifehacks is meant to solve that type of puzzle. But conventional how-to questions are outside  the scope of this site. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Robert Cartaino Okay, I will ask this question on that website.

Comment: @Jem Eripol No, buddy here is my youtube channel : goo.gl/jAtdM